# How to post a value to controller to receive Data back to view Angular 5+?

Tags: angular, api, controller

I am new to Angular so I am not sure if this is the best approach. I would like to post data from my view to my controller Api and the value that is posted from my view I want to use it as a query for my get method. If I hard code `searchVal` value to my function both my post and get method works. But as soon as I added `public string searchVal { get; set; }` to use the value from my post method as a query for my get method my app no longer displays the datas.

```js
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OperationDataController : Controller
{
    public OperationDataController()
    {
        searchVal = "";
    }

    public string searchVal { get; set; }
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<Search> GetAllTweetsByName()
    {
        Twitter twit = new Twitter();
        twit.Initialise();
        var t = await twit.Fetch(searchVal, 50, true, SearchType.Search);
        return t[0];
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<Search> GetAllTweetsByNamePost([FromBody] dynamic searchQuery)
    {
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchQuery);
        var Input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchQuery>(jsonString);
        searchVal = Input.Name;

        Twitter twit = new Twitter();
        twit.Initialise();
        var t = await twit.Fetch(Input.Name, 50, true, SearchType.Search);
        return t[0];
    }
}
```

TypeScript function:

```js
getSocialDataTwitter() {
    return this.http.get<LeftOperatorPaneltwitter>(this.baseUrl + 'api/OperationData/GetAllTweetsByName');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on the backend:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<Search> GetAllTweetsByName([FromBody] SearchQuery searchQuery)
{
    searchVal = searchQuery.Name;

    Twitter twitter = new Twitter();
    twitter.Initialise();
    var t = await twitter.Fetch(searchVal, 50, true, SearchType.Search);
    return t[0];
}
```

Angular side:

```
getSocialDataTwitter() {
    return this.http.post<LeftOperatorPaneltwitter>(this.baseUrl + 'api/OperationData/GetAllTweetsByName', searchQuery );
```

Btw, we don't know anything about your backend environment. This is for .NET Core 2.